# SQL NOT IN, != what to use?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've an csv file with plant code like X001, X005, X019...
In mysql table plantcode=username.

I want to fetch all the plantcodes from my DB table where `username` are not present in my CSV file and deleted =0.

mycode

```
    <?php
    $file = fopen("aa.csv","r");
    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r(fgetcsv($file));
    ?>
         <tr>

             <td width="10%"><label>Username</label></td>
             <td width="10%"><label>service center id</label></td>
             <td width="10%"><label>service center name</label></td>
        </tr>

        <?php
    $arr= fgetcsv($file);
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {

 $q= "SELECT * FROM `service_center` WHERE `deleted` = 0 AND username NOT LIKE '$v'";

            $r = mysql_query($q);
            $nr = mysql_num_rows($r);

            if ($nr > 0) {

                 WHILE ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
             ?>





                <td><?php echo $rows['username'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows['service_center_id'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rows['service_center_name'] ?></td>



                    <?php
                }
            }  

        else{
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $k;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "No service center found";}?></td>
            </tr>

    <?php 

    }

    fclose($file);

    ?>
```

I get output for each query like this
If username=X008 then from CSV i dont get X008 for one loop and in the next loop I get X008 and ,dont get present value plant code, But I want something like this

```
select * from service_center WHERE username != "X001, X007.." AND deleted = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

use **NOT IN($name_array)**

Pass username array in `NOT IN`

```
select * from service_center WHERE username NOT IN ("X001", "X007") AND deleted = 0;
```

Comment: just need to store $v in one array and out side of foreach need to use above query.

Comment: I think the OP should be using a statement, and the correct answer should be touching on this.

Comment: $name_array=array();
        $name_array[]=$v;

        $q= "SELECT * FROM `service_center` WHERE `deleted` = 0 AND username NOT IN ($name_array) ";    

Is this the syntax?

Comment: can you `NOT IN($name_array)` and php or mysql engine will automatically get the array as such ?

Comment: IDK, Also I am using foreach loop on an array which came from CSV file, do I need to create an array again?

Comment: Be carreful with the IN operator : it only allows you to use a maximum of 1000 values inside.